# Helvetica Font rendering heavy on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I was trying to use Helvetica font for my next project, but It was rendering heavy on Google Chrome but it was working fine on other browser.

```
/*...Helvetica.*/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helvetica';
    src: url('helvetica/Helvetica.eot');
    src: local('?'), url('helvetica/Helvetica.woff') format('woff'), url('helvetica/Helvetica.ttf') format('truetype'), url('helvetica/Helvetica.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Did anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code on html/body tag

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important
```

Comment: Dominic, thanks for the comment but it's not working.

Comment: Can you create a Codepen, so i can check it :)